# hide and show the div depending on the button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to hide and shoe the div depending on the button using html and jquert

is the button name=show status i click the button change to the name=hide  and display the div, the same function in reverse also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You could do something like this (Note the custom display attribute):

$("#btn").click(function() {
   var item = $("input[name=yourInput]");

   if (item.attr("display")) {
      item.show();
      item.attr("display", false);
   } else {
        item.hide();
        item.attr("display", true);
    }
});

<input name="yourInput" display="true" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jrz5Y/1/

Comment: @user279 it is a single button, just change #btn to your button id.

Comment: i use this method already but always said "$ null are undefined"

Comment: Have you included the jquery library? I have posted a JS Fiddle to prove it works.

Comment: i include jquery library .which one we need?

Comment: At this time, the latest is 1.9: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean variable set to a default value, and change it to it's inverse value whenever you click on the button.

depending on the state of the boolean you can execute the correct path in your method

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowHide()
    {
            if ($("#divdata").css('display') == 'none'){
            $("#divdata").show();
            $("#btnClick").val("Hide");
        }
        else{
            $("#divdata").hide();
            $("#btnClick").val("Show Status");
        }
}

</script>
```

your div will be like this.

```
<div id="divdata" style="display:none">
I have to show and hide this div.
</div>
```

Button will be like this.

```
<input id="btnClick" type="button" value="Show Status"   onclick="ShowHide()" />
```

I hope It will work.